# How to access the name for both user_id in a single query on Two table join?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL Database .I came across a situation where i have `added_by` and `update_by` these two columns in a first table where actually i am inserting user_id.

[image]

My second table name `user` contains the details of users.

[image]

Its easy to fetch the name of user on join for either `added_by` OR `updated_by`.

```
SELECT ut.ppo_id,u.name FROM upc_table ut INNER JOIN `user` u ON ut.added_by = u.user_id;
```

OR

```
SELECT ut.ppo_id,u.name FROM upc_table ut INNER JOIN `user` u ON ut.updated_by = u.user_id;
```

but i need to show the name for both added_by and updated_by using single query.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68b49a/8

```
SELECT
ut.ppo_id
,(SELECT name from user where added_by=user_id) AS added_by
,(SELECT name from user where update_by=user_id) AS updated_by
FROM upc_table ut
```

Try this..  For the pure LEFT JOIN Approach. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68b49a/38

```
SELECT
ut.ppo_id
,upd.name
,added.name
FROM upc_table ut
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
user AS upd ON ut.added_by = upd.user_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
user AS added ON ut.update_by = added.user_id
```

Comment: Could there be some more optimized way to fetch. Subquery is the solution but it will consume lot of time.

Comment: Sure..  My solution is not the only solution..  What you are requesting is to use a LEFT JOIN..

Comment: So how could we achieve it through LEFT JOIN .. I am curious.

Comment: Oh .. Its nice approach @ParkBroom .. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT ut.ppo_id,
(SELECT name FROM `user` WHERE user_id = ut.added_by) As Added_By,
(SELECT name FROM `user` WHERE user_id = ut.update_by) As Update_By
FROM upc_table ut
```